# Tabular with different row length

Tags: tables

can anyone help me coding a table like that one, please? I already have this, but I also wanted to center the first two columns text.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
Atividade &Precedência &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Duração}\\ \hline 
&&Média&Desvio padrão\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `\multirow` and `\cline`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Atividade} & \multirow{2}{*}{Precedência} &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Duração}\\ \cline{3-4} 
&&Média&Desvio padrão\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```